# UnmarshalMap using aws-go-sdk

Tags: go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

```
// UserInfo 用来解构返回的数据
type UserInfo struct {
    gender     string            `dynamo:"gender"`
    product    string            `dynamo:"product"`
    id         string            `dynamo:"id"`
    createTime int               `dynamo:"create_time"`
    name       string            `dynamo:"name"`
}

// GetUserInfoByID 根据userId在supe_user表取回用户信息
func GetUserInfoByID(userId string) (UserInfo, error) {
    queryInput := dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "userId": {
                S: aws.String(userId),
            },
        },
        TableName: aws.String("user"),
    }
    result, err := dbsession.DynamoDB.GetItem(&queryInput)
    userInfo := UserInfo{}
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return userInfo, err
    }
    unmarshalMapErr := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &userInfo)
    if unmarshalMapErr != nil {
        return userInfo, err
    }
    fmt.Println(result.Item)
    fmt.Println(userInfo.name)
    return userInfo, nil
}
```

Why is this not working? It did not throw any error, just not working...
My guess is something wrong with my `UserInfo` type, but can't figure the right way to do this, help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, a name is exported if it begins with a capital letter. You should make first letters of fields UPPERCASED to make sure they're exported, like:

```
type UserInfo struct {
    Gender     string            `dynamo:"gender"`
    Product    string            `dynamo:"product"`
    Id         string            `dynamo:"id"`
    CreateTime int               `dynamo:"create_time"`
    Name       string            `dynamo:"name"`
}
```

more info: https://www.goinggo.net/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html

Comment: This works! But shouldn't be some warning or errors posted here? I mean docs did not say anything about this....

Comment: I wonder if there is any convenient way to pick values of a struct to another.

Comment: @FrontMage The reason members need to to have their first character uppercased is that no Go library of a different package can access a member, method, type, or value of another package if the first character is not uppercased. You'll see see the same behavior in all Go marshaling libraries.

Comment: In addition to the uppercase fix, the struct tag should be dynamodbav, not dynamo. I don't think values will be marshaled like you expect them to be unless dynamodbav is used at the struct tag. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal